# No static field MAP_COPYRIGHTS_FULL of type I in class Lcom/google/android/libraries/maps/R$string; or its superclasses

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using google maps in my application, and on my phone (android 8) it is working fine, but on my older tablet (5.02) I got this error message.
I guess it has something to do with dependencies, but I can't fiugre out what. Here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //maps
    implementation name: 'maps-sdk-3.0.0-beta', ext: 'aar'

    //needed for maps
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    //tablayout
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add these to your apps strings.xml

```html
<string name="MAP_COPYRIGHTS_GOOGLE_ONLY">© %1$d Google</string>
<string name="MAP_COPYRIGHTS_FULL">© %1$d Google – Pictures © %2$d %3$s, Map Data © %4$d %5$s</string>
<string name="MAP_COPYRIGHTS_IMAGERY_ONLY">© %1$d Google – Pictures © %2$d %3$s</string>
<string name="MAP_COPYRIGHTS_MAP_DATA_ONLY">© %1$d Google – Map Data © %2$d %3$s</string>
```

There is an issue for this over at google tracker:
[google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132275121)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or why, but strings.xml is missing from maps-sdk-3.0.0-beta.aar.
Luckily, someone uploaded translations: https://github.com/greeshan/Android_4.2.x_multilang
I've downloaded another language strings.xml and copied it to 
\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppWithMap\app\libs\maps-sdk-3.0.0-beta.aar\res\values\
folder and now it works.